# Undeleting posts deleted by questioner

Tags: discussion

When a questioner deletes his/her own posts, shouldn't we respect that and not vote to undelete?

I was going to provide an example, but presumably the questioner had a reason to delete the question, so I won't draw further attention to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's usually very bad to vote to undelete qns and answers that were deleted by the original poster.  It can be some sort of attack on the dignity of participants.

Jeff wrote, in a comment on the meta.so qn, [Allow 25k+ community moderators to undelete self-deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53402/allow-25k-community-moderators-to-undelete-self-deleted-questions):

> I will only undelete something deleted by a user, when I think it was deleted in bad faith, and the underlying content adds a lot of value,

clarifying that by bad faith he had in mind such things as "sometimes users just get pissed off and decide to delete all their content out of spite."

Comment: Ah, interesting. I hadn't thought about rage-quits, er -deletes.